# How to create a high frequency graph using draw.io?

Tags: plot, graph, draw.io

**How to create a high frequency graph using draw.io?**

How can I create a high frequency graph (i.e. audio/sound graph) using draw.io tool like the following figure?

[image]

**Is it even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not possible.

Regards,